# NAs not allowed error message in attempt to plot raster object in R

Tags: raster, r

I have imported a clipped raster (performed in ArcGIS 10.1) from the National Landcover Dataset into R, but when I try to plot I get the following error message.

Error in .readCellsGDAL(x, uniquecells, layers) : 
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
In addition: Warning message:
In .readCells(x, cells, 1) : NAs introduced by coercion

I am relatively new to using rasters in R, but I cannot locate the NAs. levels(nlcd) yields the following:

```
ID  objectID    Value   Count   Red Green   Blue    Land_Cover_Class    opacity
0   1   0   4   0   0   0   Unclassified    1
1   12  11  584837  0.2784314   0.4196078   0.627451    Open Water  1
2   22  21  2247379 0.8666667   0.7882353   0.7882353   Developed, Open Space   1
3   23  22  954664  0.8470588   0.5764706   0.5098039   Developed, Low Intensity    1
4   24  23  647735  0.9294118   0   0   Developed, Medium Intensity 1
5   25  24  333254  0.6666667   0   0   Developed, High Intensity   1
6   32  31  12173780    0.6980392   0.6784314   0.6392157   Barren Land 1
7   42  41  5640937 0.4078431   0.6666667   0.3882353   Deciduous Forest    1
8   43  42  6987282 0.1098039   0.3882353   0.1882353   Evergreen Forest    1
9   44  43  957021  0.7098039   0.7882353   0.5568627   Mixed Forest    1
10  53  52  56354805    0.8 0.7294118   0.4862745   Shrub/Scrub 1
11  72  71  9100560 0.8862745   0.8862745   0.7568627   Herbaceuous 1
12  82  81  477862  0.8588235   0.8470588   0.2352941   Hay/Pasture 1
13  83  82  453351  0.6666667   0.4392157   0.1568627   Cultivated Crops    1
14  91  90  2671979 0.7294118   0.8470588   0.9176471   Woody Wetlands  1
15  96  95  495808  0.4392157   0.6392157   0.7294118   Herbaceuous wetlands    1
```

The only issue I can see being the problem is the first row.

Below is the code that I used.

```
library(rgdal) ## spatial
library(raster) ## spatial
library (rgeos) ## spatial
nlcd = raster("C:/Extract_img11.tif")
plot(nlcd)
```

I can't post Extract_img11.tif because it is too large.

Sorry for the vagueness of this question. My guess is that the clipping created the problem, but I haven't ever seen this before.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Please show all the code used. Can you point to an example file.

Comment: Please update me if you solve this. Alejandro

Comment: I had the same problem. I quickly realized that in fact you can 'load' the raster in R with raster('your_raster.tif') but it is too large to go in memory while attempting to use it with other functions.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to have been a bug with the r 'raster' package version 2.2-31 released a bit before this post. I was able to work around the issue by upgrading the package to 2.3-12 which ran the exact same code without the error.